# Sample MS Access database

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc

For JDBC-ODBC Bridge, I use a self-made `School.mdb` database with no more than 5 records.
One of the community members told me to use a 'real' database like `HL2D` (if I got the name right).
Where is this database located?
If it is available on the internet, where can I get it?

Comment: Try Google for a start.  There are any number of open source databases, for simple, single user databases, you could look at [H2DE](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) or [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) (they can both run in multi user mode as well) - oh, and they are written in pure Java

Comment: One of the big advantages of an mdb is that it is not just a database, it also includes RAD tools. Furthermore, the Jet database was a part of Windows, so did not need to be installed on Windows machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They might have meant Hypersonic SQL.  You can also try Derby, which is part of JDK 7 and higher.  Or SQL Lite.

I'd prefer all of them to MS Access.  All have type IV, pure Java JDBC drivers that will work on 64 bit operating systems.  The JDBC-ODBC bridge driver uses native code for 32 bit operating systems that hasn't been ported to 64 bit.

Five records?  You don't need a database.  A simple file on the file system loaded into a Map will do for that.

Comment: *"Five records? You don't need a database*" - Maybe not, but it is still a good way to learn (which Access "use" to be good for) - IMHO ;)